# Moen 1225 cartridge does not stay in place

Tags: shower, faucet, bathtub, replacement, cartridge

I recently replaced a Moen 1225 cartridge (for a T8350 Moen faucet).  That fixed the leak, but now when I turn on the faucet (by pulling it out) the faucet does not stay at the temperature I put it at.  The faucet handle will turn just a little bit.  The handle moves very freely.  I checked the holding screw to the cartridge and it is good and tight.  So the cartridge and the handle are moving together.  How can that be fixed?

Edit: the temp does not vary much but the faucet does move enough to make the tem change. And when turning the faucet, there is very little friction. I have similar faucets in the house and they need more effort to turn than this one for which I replaced the cartridge

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are you saying that the temperature changes when you increase the volume, or that you can't set the temperature at all?

Comment: Hello again. Your two accounts are [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/99842/peter) and [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/99839/peter-k-dunkelberger). Use the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to request that they be merged.